# Unexpected result in StringTokenizer

Tags: java, android, stringtokenizer

I have the following code which gives me an unexpected result:

```
String output = "New Record created successfully<br>Enter stops<br>";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(output);
token = st.nextToken("<br>");
msg1.setText(token);
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
       token = st.nextToken("<br>");
       msg2.setText(token);
}
```

*Actual and expected output:*

`msg1` shows *`New`* but should be *`New record created successfully`*
`msg2` shows *`stops`* but should be *`Enter stops`*

Comment: *FYI:* The javadoc of [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) says: *"`StringTokenizer` is a **legacy** class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its **use is discouraged** in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead."*

Answer (score 1):

A [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) splits the string at each position of all supplied characters in the *delimiter* argument. It does not split at the occurrence of the whole supplied string. Besides, it is a legacy class and its usage in new code is not recommended.

Use [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) which takes a regular expression that is used to tokenise the string:

```
String output = "New Record created successfully<br>Enter stops<br>";

String[] tokens = output.split("<br>");

String token = tokens[0];
System.out.println(token);
if (tokens.length > 0) {
    token = tokens[1];
    System.out.println(token);
}
```

*Output:*

```
New Record created successfully
Enter stops
```